# VBScript Case statement query

Tags: vbscript, case-statement

I'm working on a legacy application and have no way of debugging the code. I'm programmatically updating a case statement based on the values selected in the application.

My question is - Is it possible to have a Case statement with ONLY a 'Case Else'? e.g.

```
        Select Case (test)
            Case Else
                test = "this is a test"
        End Select
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

The [vbscript documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ef9w614%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) states that the case expresions are optional

```
Select Case testexpression
   [Case expressionlist-n
      [statements-n]] . . .
   [Case Else
      [elsestatements-n]]
End Select
```